# How to order api in swaggo?

Tags: go, swagger

[image]

This image is generated by Swaggo.

I would like the 'auth' section to be displayed at the top.

Additionally, I noticed that the order of APIs under each tag is not in accordance with my code.

It seems sorts them alphabetically, which is not I expected.

How can I fix this?

Here is simple code:

```
//  @Security   AuthToken
//  @Summary    Search user by id
//  @Tags       user
//  @Description
//  @Produce    json
//  @Param      userId  path    string  true    "user id"   default(testUser001)
//  @Router     /api/user/{userId} [get]
```

Comment: which middleware you're using? echo? gin?

Comment: @ttrasn I used gin

Answer (score 2):

You can arrange them by adding annotations in `main.go`

```
// @tag.name tag1
// @tag.name tag2
// @tag.name tag3
```